# Casting a webpage with autoplaying unmuted video on the Chromecast

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast

I've managed to cast a LAN hosted dashboard page to the chromecast, using https://boombatower.github.io/chromecast-dashboard/sender/.

However, the HTML5 video tag will not play without the muted attribute (and trying to unmute causes it to pause). Here is the error: "Unmuting failed and the element was paused instead because the user didn't interact with the document before". It has to do with Chrome policy, of course.

Is there any way to cause interaction with the Chromecast to perhaps allow unmuting? I've tried to press the pause button on my TV to send an event via CEC (it works on the media controller), but the videos still get muted.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I need to mark the video element using the chromecast api. So I had to create my own Cast app.

There isn't a way to do this with the given dashboard app. It wraps the user's page inside an iframe, and there is just no way to access the chromecast api from inside.